# how to use GenericIndex class in opencv

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, flann

Since `Index_` is a deprecated class in flann library, I'm trying to use `GenericIndex` class Which is a template class. I don't know how to create a object for that class.

The Class definition in flann.hpp is as below :

```
template <typename Distance>
class GenericIndex
{
public:
        typedef typename Distance::ElementType ElementType;
        typedef typename Distance::ResultType DistanceType;

        GenericIndex(const Mat& features, const ::cvflann::IndexParams& params, Distance distance = Distance());

        ~GenericIndex();

        void knnSearch(const vector<ElementType>& query, vector<int>& indices,
                       vector<DistanceType>& dists, int knn, const ::cvflann::SearchParams& params);
        void knnSearch(const Mat& queries, Mat& indices, Mat& dists, int knn, const ::cvflann::SearchParams& params);

        int radiusSearch(const vector<ElementType>& query, vector<int>& indices,
                         vector<DistanceType>& dists, DistanceType radius, const ::cvflann::SearchParams& params);
        int radiusSearch(const Mat& query, Mat& indices, Mat& dists,
                         DistanceType radius, const ::cvflann::SearchParams& params);

        void save(std::string filename) { nnIndex->save(filename); }

        int veclen() const { return nnIndex->veclen(); }

        int size() const { return nnIndex->size(); }

        ::cvflann::IndexParams getParameters() { return nnIndex->getParameters(); }

        FLANN_DEPRECATED const ::cvflann::IndexParams* getIndexParameters() { return nnIndex->getIndexParameters(); }

private:
        ::cvflann::Index<Distance>* nnIndex;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `GenericIndex` you must specify a distance functor at the template instantiation, instead of the feature type as was done with `Index_`. A number of distance functors are defined in `flann/dist.h`: `L1`, `L2`, `MinkowskyDistance`, etc. These are themselves templates, parameterized by feature type.

So, where with `Index_` you'd declare:

```
cv::flann::Index_<int> index;
```

With `GenericIndex` you do (for example):

```
cv::flann::GenericIndex<cvflann::L2<int> > index;
```

Where `cvflann::L2` is the functor that implements the [L2 norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm)-based distance metric. Notice that the functor's namespace is `cvflann`, not `cv::flann` as with `GenericIndex` (why the developers decided to have these two just-alike-but-not-quite namespaces is beyond me).

`Index_` and `GenericIndex` have otherwise pretty similar interfaces, so you'll probably won't have to change anything beyond that.

Comment: hi, can you give me some guidance on how to construct `cv::flann::GenericIndex`, I found opencv doc very hard to understand. Thank you very much. `cv::flann::GenericIndex<cvflann::L2<int> > index(feature, params, Distance)`, I know feature is cv::Mat, but I am confused with how to construct params and Distance. Really need some help here.

Comment: As explained [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d18/classcv_1_1flann_1_1GenericIndex.html#a8fff14185f9f3d2f2311b528f65b146c), for the `params` argument you must create an instance of a `IndexParams` subclass, e.g. `KDTreeIndexParams`, `CompositeIndexParams`, etc. Different parameter subclasses will produce indexes with different search strategies. The `distance` argument can be omitted, since it is given a default value.